# Is a battery with broken ACPI protected from overcharging?

Tags: battery

I have accidently completely discharged an old laptop's battery and its ACPI is not working now. (Reporting 0% or no battery etc.)

I think the mechanism of detecting voltage (or battery remaining) is also completely broken because I can't check the remaining battery by hardware button on battery(Mac-like button by dell).

Now, the question is, is the battery protected from overcharging? Is it safe to use this battery?

BTW, device: Dell XPS M1210

Comment: Batteries are not cheap, but their cost is negligible when compared with the expense of a fire. It's simply not worth the risk. Remove the battery and run on mains power until you can replace it. Under no circumstances leave the battery on charge while you are not in the room.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Battery protection circuits are designed to be "fail-safe" in the literal sense of the term. If you discharge a battery too far it will permanently disable itself like yours has. There's no need to protect it from overcharge because you probably won't be able to charge it at all.

Comment: Nope, actually it's working without ACPI.

Comment: In that case whatever problem the battery has isn't ACPI related.